# what is the maven repository for jconnect2.jar

Tags: java, maven

I am working on maven java project,I need to check if the connection to db is success every 2 hours.

I am loading Sybase db driver url. so I need maven repository dependency details for jconnec2.jar

is there any difference if I add the jar in my class path in eclipse if there is no maven dependency?
is it good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine, you can do that rather than use a Maven repository.  You can also add it to your `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory in Eclipse, too, so it deploys when you create a package.

Another alternative if you want to use Maven is to host a local repository and manually add jconnec2.jar to it.

Comment: Thanks, my maven module will be java application and is not web application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jTDS](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds) for Sybase or [add the driver to your local repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

Comment: if I have to add it to repository, what could be the group id and other details?

Comment: That's arbitrary; it's not going to be used by people outside your organisation

Comment: Ok,it means I can use some com.xxx.xx as group id right?

Comment: As long as you're not sharing the jar with others, you can use whatever you want, as long as the characters are legal on your filesystem.

Comment: Aside, does Sybase SQL Anywhere = Sybase ASA ?

Comment: @mmcrae according to [this post](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/discussion/129584/thread/176aa18d/#6918), it does not, but that was also from 2011, so things may have changed since.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sybase</groupId>
   <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependencies>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
     <artifactId>jconnect</artifactId>
     <version>6.05-26023</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using "com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver" It is saying classnotfound exception

Comment: Emm.. @Khalil did you try this?

Comment: you try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ,

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```